# How to correctly use variables in SQL queries securely in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

What is the proper format to use variables within SQL queries? Yes I know my code is not secure for because its not hashed and other flaws but I just can't get it to work.

```
include 'config/database.php'; // DB connection.
$password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `login` (`id`, `username`, `password`, `question`) VALUES (NULL, \'test\', \$password\, \'test\')';

if (mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
echo 'Done!';
}

else
{
echo 'No.';
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

The error

```
Connection worked!
```

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_real_escape_string() in C:\xampp\htdocs\hashing\password.php:3 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\hashing\password.php on line 3

Its just a simple PHP form that posts to the following PHP script. I have also got the SQL query formatted in phpMyAdmin. Thanks!

Comment: Your PHP installation probably just didn't ship with the `mysql*` extension because it's deprecated. You might have `mysqli*` installed though. `mysql_real_escape_string()` => `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. Though this won't help the security issue.

Comment: Do _not_ try to manually escape values. Instead read about the advantages of using "prepared statements" combined with "parameter binding" for a secure usage. _This is all documented. Read the documentation!_

Comment: If you are using PHP 7 then `mysql_*` functions are no longer available. I assume your `database.php` is using `mysqli_*` functions, right?

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat). Make sure that you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Answer (score -1):

Your xampp must come with MySQLi instead of MySQL (that is deprecated now), so you have to use `mysqli_real_escape_string($var)` instead of `mysql_real_escape_string($var)`

Also you have to escape each variable you will put in your SQL query, and include it :) ! (care in your SQL query you are using single quote which are not interpreting $password), it's more like that :

`$sql = 'INSERT INTO`login`(`id`,`username`,`password`,`question`) VALUES (NULL, \'test\', \''.$password.'\', \'test\')';`

Comment: Deprecated was for PHP 5.5.0. Now it's completely removed.

Comment: We don't know which version of PHP he is using, but yes now it's removed you're right :)

Comment: I've done the following and updated the mysql_real function to the mysqli statement and now I'm getting this for an error? 

Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\xampp\htdocs\hashing\password.php on line 3
No.

Comment: You have to pass the database handle in that function. Per docs

`mysqli_real_escape_string ( mysqli $link , string $escapestr )`

Comment: Here is the documentation to help you ;)  - http://php.net/manual/fr/mysqli.real-escape-string.php